# Eclipse SVN Subversive - ignores all my files

Tags: java, eclipse, svn

I've been using SVN with Eclipse for quite a while without any issues.  I have several workspaces created and just recently on one of them, when I share a project to SVN - it ignores all the files???

I've checked the settings under Preferences->Team and they are the same as the other workspaces - nothing extra in the Ignored Resources list - but I have to manually add each file after sharing the project (Java files) - and then I get the following message:

**You have explicitly asked to version control one or more resources that otherwise would have been ignored. Continue?**

The workspace name is WS_Integrations - and I thought that there might be something in the ignore list which was being triggered with that name - but I can't see anything?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on the project, `Team` > `Show Properties` and edit values for `SVN:ignore`

**Update**

The cause here was the workspace folder had svn configuration set to ignore. Resolved it by removing this config.

Comment: Hi James - when I do that it doesn't actually show many any properties - just a blank area...  Also this is occurring for all projects in the workspace.

Comment: Is there a possibility of your workspace has .svn configuration which is set to ignore?

Comment: Thanks James - that was it indeed!  I checked using the svn on the folder containing the workspace - and it had been set to ignore...  No idea why?  But thank you!